# Is there any Power Bi api available for providing access to Dataset?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-api

I have found api for adding user to workspace(group) as well as Add Datasource user. I would like to know, if there is any api available for adding user to dataset?
From the Power Bi Web portal, this is accessed by:
Workspace -> **Datasets + Dataflows** -> select the three dots menu icon near to the Dataset name and click **Manage Permissions**. Now, select **Direct Access** and **Add/Remove** users here with share/build permissions.

I couldn't find an api for this process. When I tracked the network calls, it is calling the url portion:
redirect.analysis.windows.net/**metadata/access**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataset permissions are part of item permission so you can't override the workspace permissions and can be granted who has at least same level of permission. There are POST APIs where you can add new permission to dataset but not to remove permissions and then PUT APIs where you can update the user's permissions and GET APIs where you can get list of principals that have access to dataset.

Coming to the adding user to dataset I can't find one API for that. But A user's role in workspace implicitly grants the permission on the dataset in the workspace. So if you want to add user then you can use that API you found. And then You can update the permissions for the specific user using these APIs.

Please refer to the link for detailed information.

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/datasets-permissions#item-permissions

https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/groups/add-group-user
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-permissions

Answer (score 0):

We don't have the option of providing the access through api.

But we can create a Distribution List, by adding users to the list access will be granted accordingly

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I was trying to add some AD groups to a Dataset using the API. (Similar to adding users to workspace using API)